# Apache patch for case sensitive domain name

Tags: apache-2.2

is there something like this

http://yost.com/computers/apache-redirect/apache-patch.html

is there something like this but as part of apache, this patch is for 1.3.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Domain names, by definition, aren't case sensitive.  A patch to try and make Apache match domain names on a case-sensitive basis would be a nightmare.

Comment: +1 agreed. The behavior implemented by that patch is a blatant violation of RFC 2616, which defines the HTTP protocol. (Well... I guess you could argue that _technically_ it's allowed, it's just a Very Bad Idea.)